# How to filter keys in params hash using permit or require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller it expects one hash with the following keys :

```
{:username,:password,:age}
params =  {"username"=>"john", "password"=>"secret"}
```

`params` is an object of `ActionController::Parameters` class. Now controller should give an error ":age" parameter is missing.
 How can I do this with require/permit in Rails?  Or is there any other better way to put validations on input parameters in Rails other than `strong_parameters`?

Comment: chain several `require` http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require, or build your own object with validations

Comment: correct we can use require but the problem with using "require" is i can validate only one key at a time...:(

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a simple validation method in your model. Something like this:

```
validates :age, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

You should also permit :age in your strong_parameters method in the controller. As Mohammed pointed out, this will require something like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :age)
```

But that has nothing to do with validation. It's just to whitelist the params provided by the user through a form, in order to prevent certain types of attacks in the mass assignment of attributes when creating or updating your model.

Once your params get whitelisted, your validation callbacks will kick in before creating or saving the new object. If the attribute "age" is missing or nil, the previous method will give a validation error,which you can read in @user.errors.messages or whatever the name of your model is. In this way, your object will not be saved unless :age is not blank.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what u mentioned was correct, and ur suggestion is also good, but i have a problem with is approach. We can't add Active Record Validations on top of NoSql in rails. Please correct me if i'm wrong..:)

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention that you were using nosql. Frankly, I don't know the answer to your question. I have never used nosql databases with rails. I usually find that postgres native types, like hstore, give me enough flexibility within a sql framework to avoid the potential problems involved in using mongo and the like. But, as I said, I have very little knowledge about these databses. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use permit as:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :age)
```

and is your age param is presenting in your form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>

   .....
<% end %>
```

as basically Action expect your params hash is as following:

```
params{"user" => {"name": name, "password": password, "age": 13 }}
```

Comment: you dont answer `Now controller should give an error ":age" parameter is missing`

Comment: thanks for ur resp guys, few points i want to tell u: 1. I dont have any view part, its completely back_end validation. 2. I'm using NoSql, so i can't add any active record validations on it.      
So is there any way to do validation on input parameters.